# WooCommerce - where to change 'product-category' path?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce product categories have paths such as: http://example.com/product-category/my-category/ .

I understand that in older versions of WooCommerce, you could set the 'product-category' part of the URL by going to WooCommerce > Settings > Pages. However, in the current version of WooCommerce, that option doesn't seem to be available. So where can I find/access the field that holds this info?

(Ultimately, I don't want to change this path, but I want to find out where WooCommerce stores it so that I can manually build some category URLs in the correct manner without hardcoding/guessing the 'product-category' part.)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old and you probably resolved it.

However if anyone else is looking for this answer.

The option is part of WordPress permalinks you can find them under Settings > permalinks

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've gone into Settings > Permalinks and changed the `Product category base` field (and the `Category base` field), but no change in the front end - my product categories still include product-category in the URL. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a caching plugin getting in the middle?